# With full-site-editing menus, how do I create a non-linking top-level menu item with linking sub-pages

Tags: block-editor

I did this all the time pre-full-site-editing, back when we all built menus under Appearance. But without the Menu option under Appearance anymore, how do I do this?

Is it only possible by way of a home-rolled function in functions.php or in javascript?
I tried a function under `add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'delink_menu_item', 10, 2 );` but there were no `$items` or `$args`. Does FSE use a new function or filter? I could do this with jQuery, but not my favorite approach.

Thoughts?

Comment: I still have menu options under appearance.  None the less just set the target of a top level to `#` and it won't link to anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't the Menu under Appearance in an FSE environment.

Answer (score 5):

The new FSE editor uses a new filter, if you want to hook into that you can do it in two ways:

By hooking the individual block rendering:

```php
add_filter( 'render_block_core/navigation-link', 'test_render_navigation_link', 10, 3);

function test_render_navigation_link($block_content, $block) {
    $attributes = $block["attrs"];
    
    // string replace the href if you want, by checking the content of $attributes
    return $block_content;
}
```

or by hooking the prerender for the entire navigational menu:

```php
add_filter( 'block_core_navigation_render_inner_blocks', 'replace_nav_blockitem_href');

function replace_nav_blockitem_href( $items ) {
    
    // Loop through the items (they are nested)
    foreach ($items as $key => $item) {
        //recursive loop through $item->inner_blocks
        //once you have found your item then set the attribute url to empty
        $item->parsed_block["attrs"]["url"] = null;
    }
    return $items;
}
```

The rendering of the navigation item will not output the href if the url is empty, this can be seen in the source code of the rendering:
https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/0cb8475c0d07d23893b1d73d755eda5f12024585/src/wp-includes/blocks/navigation-link.php#L173

This is the line where the first filter is called:
https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/28f10e4af559c9b4dbbd1768feff0bae575d5e78/src/wp-includes/class-wp-block.php#L306

This is the line where the second filter is called:
https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/0cb8475c0d07d23893b1d73d755eda5f12024585/src/wp-includes/blocks/navigation.php#L512

Comment: Ah, so a new filter. So helpful! Hopefully, this will make it into the docs eventually.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it was too easy to turn to jQuery. I saved it to a .js file, enqueued it, now good to go:

```
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
        
    $j(function() {
        //remove link from top-level menu items
        $j('ul.wp-block-page-list li.has-child > a').removeAttr('href');
    });
```